# Matplotlib change the bar color if a condition is met

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I am trying to build a Figure with 2 subplots.

If the Item is in `ax` and `ax1` the color of the bar is blue.
If the item is in `ax` and not in `ax1` the bar color should be green.
If the item is not in `ax` and it is in `ax1` the bar color should be red.
so in my example:

The bar `Exploit` should be green and `XSS` should be red.

Is there a way to do this with Matplotlib?

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import OrderedDict
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from  Processesing import dataProcess
from Sizeconvertor import Szconv




def chartmak (curvdic,prevdic,imgname,unit) :
Colors =[]
ImgName=imgname
D={}
D1={}
D=curvdic
D1=prevdic
if len(D):
    listo=list(D.items())
    listo1=list(D1.items())
    if len(listo) < 10:
        listo.extend([('', 0)] * (10 - len(listo)))

    if len(listo1) < 10:
        listo1.extend([('', 0)] * (10 - len(listo1)))

    values1 = [v for l, v in listo1]
    values = [v for l, v in listo]

    Dict=listo
    Dict1=listo1

    fig, (ax,ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2,figsize=(12, 5))
    n = len(Dict)
    n1 = len(Dict1)
    #--------------add the 1 barchart
    ax.barh(range(n), values, align='center', fc='#80d0f1', ec='w')
    ax.set_yticks(range(n))
    ax.set_yticklabels(['' if e == 0 else Szconv(e,unit) for e in values], color='gray')# add the unit
    ax.tick_params(pad=10)
    for i, (label, val) in enumerate(Dict):
        ax.annotate(label.title(), xy=(10, i), fontsize=10, va='center')
    for spine in ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'):
        ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.set_title('curmonth')

    #----------add the secound plot
    ax1.barh(range(n1), values1, align='center', fc='#80d0f1', ec='w')
    ax1.set_yticks(range(n1))
    ax1.set_yticklabels(['' if e == 0 else Szconv(e,unit) for e in values1], color='gray')#this need more work to put the GB or the TB
    ax1.tick_params(pad=10)
    for i, (label, val) in enumerate(Dict1):
      ax1.annotate(label.title(), xy=(10, i), fontsize=10, va='center')
    for spine in ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'):
        ax1.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
    ax1.xaxis.set_ticks([])
    ax1.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
    ax1.invert_yaxis()
    ax1.set_title('PrevMonth')
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------

    #fig.set_size_inches(4, 3.5)

    plt.savefig("BarChart/"+ImgName,bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()

   Testdic =OrderedDict([('Exploit', 14664), ('Botnet', 123), ('Virus', 52)])
   Testdic2 =OrderedDict([('Botnet', 1252), ('Virus', 600), ('XSS', 452)])
   imgname="TestImageformt.png"
   unit = "transaction"
   chartmak(Testdic,Testdic2,imgname,unit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color of the `Rectangle` patches that `barh` creates after its been plotted based on your conditions.

I modified your code a little to remove some of the unnecessary parts and make it run. I hope its clear below what its doing. You can use `ax.patch[i].set_color('r')` to change the color of patch `i` to red, for example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import OrderedDict

fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

Testdic1 =OrderedDict([('Exploit', 14664), ('Botnet', 123), ('Virus', 52)])
Testdic2 =OrderedDict([('Botnet', 1252), ('Virus', 600), ('XSS', 452)])

list1 = list(Testdic1.items())
list2 = list(Testdic2.items())

n1 = len(list1)
n2 = len(list2)

values1 = [v for l,v in list1]
values2 = [v for l,v in list2]

ax1.barh(range(n1),values1,align='center', fc='#80d0f1', ec='w')
ax2.barh(range(n2),values2,align='center', fc='#80d0f1', ec='w')

# ====================================
# Here's where we change colors
# ====================================
for i,(label,val) in enumerate(list1):
    if label.title() in Testdic2:
        pass # leave it blue
    else:
        ax1.patches[i].set_color('g')
for i,(label,val) in enumerate(list2):
    if label.title() in Testdic1:
        pass # leave it blue
    else:
        ax2.patches[i].set_color('r')
# ====================================

ax1.set_yticks(range(n1))
ax2.set_yticks(range(n2))

for i, (label, val) in enumerate(list1):
    ax1.annotate(label.title(), xy=(10, i), fontsize=10, va='center')

for i, (label, val) in enumerate(list2):
    ax2.annotate(label.title(), xy=(10, i), fontsize=10, va='center')

ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax2.invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This exactly what i wanted i will modify the code and use your Idea thank you

Comment: i have a question why did you use Bar1 and Bar2 and never used them before,

Comment: Just something I tried but didn't end up using. I'll edit it out